# Getting Random Scientific numbers instead of inputs

Tags: c++

Like the title states, I am getting random scientific numbers when I store them in an array and try to output them . I'm not sure why they are changing as there were no operations being done on the numbers. Due to the numbers changing I get the incorrect Fahrenheit temperature.

Sample input: days 0-6 = 12
I get sunday = 0, monday = 1.32657e. etc The numbers are random, not even the same although the input stays the same

```
int main()
{
    const int DAYS_OF_WEEK = 7;
    const double MAXIMUM_TEMPERATURE = 60;
    const double MINIMUM_TEMPERATURE = -90 ;
    double temperature;
    int dayCount;
    double fahrenheit;
    double temperatures[6];
    string daysOfWeek[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};//string array for the days of the week

    for(int dayCount = 0; dayCount < DAYS_OF_WEEK; dayCount++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the Temperature for " << daysOfWeek[dayCount] << " in Celsius: ";  // re-prompt for temperature
        cin >> temperature;

        while(cin.fail())// checks to see if cin failed
        {
            cin.clear(); 
            cout << "\nInvalid input. Only numeric values, please try again. "; // re-prompt
            cin >> temperature; // try to get the value again
            fflush(stdin); //clear input buffer
        }//end while

        if(temperature > MAXIMUM_TEMPERATURE || temperature < MINIMUM_TEMPERATURE)
        {
            cout << "\nInvalid input. Temperature must be between " << MINIMUM_TEMPERATURE <<" and " << MAXIMUM_TEMPERATURE <<". Please try again." << endl;// re-prompt user for temp between ranges
            cin >> temperature;
        }
        else
        {
            temperature = temperatures[dayCount];
        }//end else
    }//end for
    cout << "Temperatures for the Week.\n_________________________________________________";

    for (int dayCount = 0; dayCount < DAYS_OF_WEEK; dayCount++)
    {           
        cout << "\nTemperature for " << daysOfWeek[dayCount] << " in Celsius is: " << temperatures[dayCount];
        fahrenheit = (5.0/9.0) * (temperatures[dayCount] + 32);
        cout << "In Fahrenheit it is:" << fahrenheit;
    }   //end for

    return 0;
}//end main
```

Comment: in your line `if (temperature > MAXIMUM_TEMPERATURE...` you should make that a `while` loop and get rid of the `else`

Comment: @mstbaum Just did that before you commented it, but the program now crashes after all 7 temps have been inputted

Comment: See @G.Ko's comment on the below answer

Comment: if you have access to c++11 or better, you should prefer to use `std::array` over c-style arrays. You can get the `size` of a `std::array`, for example instead of using `DAYS_OF_WEEK` you could use `daysOfWeek.size()`. You could also use a range based for loop with `std::array`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that in this line

```
            {
            temperature = temperatures[dayCount];
        }//end else
```

you meant the other direction

```
temperatures[dayCount] = temperature;
```

as the assignment is the right side into the left side.

The reason for the garbage values is that temperatures wasn't initialized and had garbage values in it. Throughout the process, you did not change the values of that array because of the error above.

Comment: That was the problem -_-. Thanks for helping me with my stupiditity

Comment: Will as soon as it lets me

Comment: This actually brings up a far scarier error, The program crashes once all of the temperatures have been inputted

Comment: `double temperatures[6];` means that only 6 cells are available (0 through 5) and you need 7 for every day of the week. Change this to `double temperatures[7];` and you're good to go